# cython failed or I did wrong?

Tags: python, import, module, cython

I can `import teapot` in the interactive python:

```
#teapot.py
class _A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

def _gen(c,AB):
    class ABC(AB):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.c = c
    return ABC

_AC = _gen(3,_A)


print(_AC)
print(_AC())
```

But after I `cythonize -X language_level=3 -i teapot.py`, and start a python interactive session, and `import teapot`, the interactive session quits directly. What is wrong?

```
 Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

cython                    0.29.10          py37h6538335_0    conda-forge

python                    3.7.4                h5263a28_0
```

Comment: There is package `test` already in the installation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/__init__.py, so probably this is what is imported on `import test`. You can see it in `test.__file__`.

Comment: There must be a duplicate somewhere, because this problems pops up pretty often - but I wasn't able to find one quickly. Maybe @DavidW knows one?

Comment: @ead I've definitely seen it before. I think it's often just been dealt with in the comments (like here) so a good duplicate may not exist. I'll see if I can find one, but it's going to be really hard to search for though.

Comment: The thing I'm a puzzled by is why compiling it makes any difference. At least on my system it'll always find the one that appears first in the path so `test.py` should fail too. Without knowing this it's difficult to write a good answer (otherwise I'd be tempted to edit this question into something canonical and make this the duplicate).

Comment: I changed test.py to teapot.py, and I found the problem as well. Please see my answer below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

change the line to

```
      super(ABC, self).__init__()
```

It is clear to me now Cython has not catch up yet. It is a relative new feature of Python. It took me several days!

Comment: Interestingly you only see this bug with the `gen` function. With `class ABC(_A)` defined outside the `gen` function it works. It'd probably be useful if you reported this [on the Cython bug tracker](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues) since this looks like something that should work but doesn't

Comment: Thanks, it is good to know Cython can parse super() when it is not nested in the gen function. I would avoid that altogether though. I agree with you it is supposed to work hence it is a sneaky bug, which took me days to figured out. Will report on Cython bug tracker.